# Run AppleScript when notification is receieved

Tags: macos, applescript, notifications

I have a script that runs perfectly but I want it to initialise when I receive a notification with the title "Bricks + Agent". Even better if I can actually put the subtitle text into the dialog box as well

```
set theDialogText to "Have you uploaded the inspection report to Bricks + Agent?"
display dialog theDialogText buttons {"No", "Yes"} default button "No" cancel button "Yes"
--> Result: {{button returned:"No"}
open location "https://services.bricksandagent.com/Dashboard/SpDashboard#/sp"
```

Comment: That isn’t how AppleScript works. It doesn’t sit in the background silently waiting or listening for things to happen in order to respond (the exception being Folder Actions).  Scripts either get triggered manually, or by another application that has the capability to run scripts.

Answer (score 0):

What macOS version are you on? I figured out something so I can auto-dismiss those annoying persistent `updates available` notifications (which happen regardless of auto-update settings), but apparently the Applescript functions for notifications change vastly between OS versions. My solution is not really "act when receiving a notification", but rather it constantly checks visible notifications for certain strings. That's pretty much the best you can do with just Applescript. It should work fine on at least **Monterey** and possibly anything newer.

The top part is some config, then at the very bottom I've added a comment to indicate where you would add your handling. You should probably just read through the entire script anyway. =] As a bonus I've also included the auto-dismiss functionality, which should be language independent. Also I'm not sure if subtitles still exist, because none showed up in my test cases. But I added a comment where you could try to retrieve them.

```
global notificationStrings
set notificationStrings to {"Bricks + Agent"}

-- These *must* be the English names, since they will be translated to whatever's currently on the notification
global closeStrings
set closeStrings to {"Close", "Clear All"}

global accessCheckTitle
set accessCheckTitle to "Notifications Monitor"

-- An error message will be directly appended to this
global accessCheckSubtitle
set accessCheckSubtitle to "This app needs both Accessibility and Automation access:\n\n"

global buttonOk
set buttonOk to "Close"
global buttonSysPrefs
set buttonSysPrefs to "Open System Preferences"

-- Amount of ticks before we reload the strings (at return 3 this is about 300 seconds, or 5 min)
global reloadStringsInterval
set reloadStringsInterval to 100

-- END OF CONFIG

global reloadStringsTicks
set reloadStringsTicks to -1
global closeStringsl10n
set closeStringsl10n to {}

on idle
    checkNotifications()
    return 3 -- Delay for next run (seconds)
end idle

on quit
    continue quit -- Allows the script to quit
end quit

on checkNotifications()
    try
        -- All of these throw errors when they've explicitly been denied access, otherwise they'll prompt (at least on the very first time)
        tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents" to set ncenterProcess to the first process whose bundle identifier = "com.apple.notificationcenterui" -- For Automation access on System Events
        set ncenter to path to application id "com.apple.notificationcenterui" -- For Automation access on Notification Centre
        tell ncenterProcess to exists window 1 -- For Accessibility access
    on error errmsg
        -- A try is necessary to handle the cancel button without "crashing" (thanks Apple)
        set openSysPrefs to false
        try
            set res to (display dialog (accessCheckSubtitle & errmsg) with title accessCheckTitle buttons {buttonOk, buttonSysPrefs} default button buttonSysPrefs cancel button buttonOk with icon stop)
            if button returned of res is equal to buttonSysPrefs then
                set openSysPrefs to true
            end if
        end try

        if openSysPrefs then
            open location "x-apple.systempreferences:com.apple.preference.security?Privacy_Accessibility"
        end if

        -- Always need to quit here so that we can pick up on any newly granted permissions next time we run
        delay 30
        quit
    end try

    set reloadStringsTicks to reloadStringsTicks + 1
    if reloadStringsTicks is equal to 0 or reloadStringsTicks is greater than or equal to reloadStringsInterval then
        set l10nTmp to {}
        try
            repeat with closeString in closeStrings
                set the end of l10nTmp to localized string closeString in bundle ncenter
            end repeat
        on error
            -- I think this can happen if this script runs too early after logging in, so let's make sure we'll immediately try again on the next run
            set reloadStringsTicks to -1
            return
        end try
        set closeStringsl10n to l10nTmp
        set reloadStringsTicks to 0
    end if

    tell application id "com.apple.SystemEvents"
        tell ncenterProcess
            -- The main window may not always (immediately/fully) exist apparently
            try
                set allNotifications to groups of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
            on error
                return
            end try

            repeat with checkNotification in allNotifications
                -- It may have already (been) closed in the meantime
                try
                    set nTitle to the value of static text 1 of checkNotification
                    --set nContents to the value of static text 2 of checkNotification
                    -- There *may* be a static text 3 for subtitles, but it didn't exist in my test cases

                    if nTitle is in notificationStrings then
                        -- This is where you would add your dialog and other handling, for example (to dismiss the notification afterwards):
                        repeat with checkAction in actions of checkNotification
                            if description of checkAction is in closeStringsl10n then
                                try
                                    perform checkAction
                                end try
                                delay 2 -- Give it some time to close
                            end if
                        end repeat
                    end if
                end try
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
end checkNotifications
```

Save it as an `Application`, while disabling `Show startup screen` and **enabling** `Stay open after run handler`. Adding it to your startup items should work just fine.